# Replace nodes in xml

Tags: r, xml

Is anyone have I idea how to replace xml nodes using XML library (or any other R libraries):

Here an example:

```
<str>
  <head>
    <id>1234</id>
  </head>
  <elements>
    <other>
        <code>Y</code>
    </other>
    <element id=1>
        <code>A</code>
        <code>B</code>
        <code>C</code>
    </element>
    <element id=2>
        <code>D</code>
        <code>E</code>
        <code>F</code>
    </element>
  </elements>
</str>
```

I woulid like to replace only whildren in **element** tag with **id=2**:

```
<code>D</code>
<code>E</code>
<code>F</code>
```

by:

```
<code>G</code>
<code>H</code>
```

(Note that number of **code** to replaced are not the same, here 3 codes to replace by 2, but it could be 2 to replace by 3, or any other combinaison)
in node **element id=2**, to finaly have:

```
<str>
  <head>
    <id>1234</id>
  </head>
  <elements>
    <annex>
        <txt>Annex 1</txt>
        <txt>Annex 2</txt>
    </annex>
    <other>
        <code>Y</code>
    </other>
    <element id=1>
        <code>A</code>
        <code>B</code>
        <code>C</code>
    </element>
    <element id=2>
        <code>G</code>
        <code>H</code>
    </element>

  </elements>
</str>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `xml2`. Note that your input has to be valid XML - in your example, the last `<element>` should be `</element>`. Anyway, making this change and saving it as `test.xml`, I can do

```r
library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml("test.xml")
nodes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//element/code")
xml_text(nodes) <- c("D", "E", "F")
write_xml(doc, "test2.xml")
```

And now I have the file `test2.xml` which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<str>
  <head>
    <id>1234</id>
  </head>
  <elements>
    <annex>
      <txt>Annex 1</txt>
      <txt>Annex 2</txt>
    </annex>
    <other>
      <code>Y</code>
    </other>
    <element>
      <code>D</code>
      <code>E</code>
      <code>F</code>
    </element>
  </elements>
</str>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can you do this in this xml:

Comment: <str>
  <head>
    <id>1234</id>
  </head>
  <elements>
    <annex>
      <txt>Annex 1</txt>
      <txt>Annex 2</txt>
    </annex>
    <z>
 <code>OO</code>
    </z>
    <element>
      <code>D</code>
      <code>E</code>
      <code>F</code>
    </element>
  </elements>
</str>

Comment: @Po78 That is the xml I used in the example above - the xml from your question. I'm not sure what you're asking me here.

Comment: I modify the xml, now there is also a code tag in other nodes, and I just want to modify children of the element children

Comment: @Po78 then change to `xml_find_all(doc, "//element/code")`

Comment: And element tag could contains for example 3 children, and I whant to replace them by x children (could be 3 but also less or more)

Comment: @Po78 It's very difficult to try to answer a question like this via comments. If you want to edit your question to make it the question you really wanted to ask, I can have a look at a more definite example. As it is, I answered the question you asked and you are now adding complexities to it in the comments, which just doesn't work.

Comment: I update the xml example in my original message, you can see that there is also a code tag in Other tag, and I want to replace only tags under element tag

Comment: @Po78 see my updated answer to reflect your updated question.